# Does H+ in the ocean bind with water to form H3O+ or with carbonate ions to form HCO3-?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry

I've read so many references on the Internet about ocean acidification and basically it can be described by the following equations
This is when $\ce{CO2}$ dissolves into ocean to form $\ce{H2CO3}$: $$\ce{CO2 + H2O <--> H2CO3 <--> H+ + HCO3-}$$
This is when excess $\ce{CO2}$ reacts with pre-existing carbonate ions to form additional bicarbonate: $$\ce{CO2 + H2O + CO3^2- -> 2HCO3-}$$
Based on the two equations, I can tell that $\ce{H+}$ which are positively charged are consuming $\ce{CO3^2-}$ which are negatively charged and good for shells to make unnecessary bicarbonate, so my first thought was to remove $\ce{H+}$ only. But then my chem teacher said that $\ce{H+}$ can also bond with $\ce{H2O}$ to form $\ce{H3O+}$ and that needed to be separated back into water and $\ce{H+}$ and only then can $\ce{H+}$ be removed.

I'm so confused, are both methods the same? And any suggestions on how I can attract hydrogen ions together?

Comment: Acidic protons are hard to capture. They will jump wherever they feel like until they have found a reasonably strong base.